# Unable to install base64enc package in R

Tags: r

This is the error message I get while trying to install base64enc as a dependencie of FastRweb:

```
> install.packages('base64enc',,'http://www.rforge.net/')
Aviso en install.packages("base64enc", , "http://www.rforge.net/") :
 argument 'lib' is missing: using '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
probando la URL 'http://www.rforge.net/src/contrib/base64enc_0.1-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7186 bytes
URL abierta
==================================================
downloaded 7186 bytes

* installing *source* package ‘base64enc’ ...
** libs
gcc -I/usr/share/R/include      -fpic  -std=gnu99 -O3 -pipe  -g -c base64.c -o base64.o
gcc -I/usr/share/R/include      -fpic  -std=gnu99 -O3 -pipe  -g -c uriencode.c -o uriencode.o
gcc -I/usr/share/R/include      -fpic  -std=gnu99 -O3 -pipe  -g -c utf8.c -o utf8.o
utf8.c: In function ‘utf8_check’:
utf8.c:75: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XLENGTH’
gcc -shared -o base64enc.so base64.o uriencode.o utf8.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/base64enc/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
Aviso: ./man/dataURI.Rd:30: unknown macro '\href'
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  imposible cargar la biblioteca compartida '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/base64enc/libs/base64enc.so':
  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/base64enc/libs/base64enc.so: undefined symbol: XLENGTH
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/base64enc’

The downloaded packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpBfdYFV/downloaded_packages’
Mensajes de aviso perdidos
In install.packages("base64enc", , "http://www.rforge.net/") :
  installation of package 'base64enc' had non-zero exit status
>
```

Looks like the package is downloaded but something is broken in my config or in the installation script.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried with just a `install.packages('base64enc')` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux, the easiest is to try to install it directly from the repository, e.g.

`sudo apt-get install r-cran-base64enc`

In this way, it will install as well any additional packages needed. R-CRAN packages are also available this way, at least in Debian and related distributions (Ubuntu, Mint).

Comment: Yes, using Debian, but still in Squeeze, where `r-cran-base64enc` is not available :(